# Asignment operation in jquery

Tags: jquery

As shown in code below I am trying to dynamically change value of one input field using value of another field using jquery. However this isn't working and dev tool gives the error:

> Invalid left-hand side in assignment

How do I implement this statement correctly?

```
$("#hf-"+semNumToCopy).val() = $("#hf").val();
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrong order, try this:

```
$("#hf-"+semNumToCopy).val($("#hf").val());
```